# Changing the extent of similar raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, extents, modis

I have two MODIS evapotranspiration rasters and their information is given below.

**Desirable raster extents:**

[image]

**Erratic raster extents:**

[image]

I want to change the erratic raster extent to desirable raster extent. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the raster data projection. The desired raster extent is in a Geographic Coordinate Reference System ( CRS) ,while the erratic is in a projected CRS. Kindly reproject the raster data to get your desired results. The tool to use is the Warp tool which you can access in QGIS from  menu bar>raster>projection>Warp.
It's easy to use but you could check this YouTube video for the steps: https://youtu.be/6HkMxDijgbs.

Comment: I tried the warp (reproject) but it does not change. The issue is something else, I think.

Comment: Yes, the second raster is representing the values in a PCS, but I don't understand how can this shows the same CRS then? Can extent have different values than the CRS?  @G.S.J,, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33374/modify-raster-extents-in-qgis#:~:text=Now%20lets%20change%20extent%20for,extent%20of%20the%20output%20raster see if this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the second raster is in a projected coordinate system but the CRS attached to it is a geographic one. The solution is changing the CRS to a projected one, where the coordinates will be expressed in meters (UTM CRS perhaps) and then reprojecting the raster to EPSG:4326 if this is needed.

To reformulate, the coordinates encoded in the raster are in meters while a CRS with degree units is attached to it. You need to attach the right CRS to the raster. Reprojecting will not fix the problem.